# How to avoid including google api twice, when you need both key and places-library?

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm using both Google API for [Key](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys) and [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[some key]"></script> 

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

but was wondering how to avoid including the google api twice, because then it'd say
"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=[some key]"></script>
```